# Cron making cached files unwritable

Tags: php, permissions, cron, centos

I have a cron job that I've set up to run every five minutes.  Because this cron job is not being run through apache, I believe if it ends up touching the website's server-side cache files (which it does frequently), that those cache files end up no longer being writable by apache, and so I get all these errors about not being able to write to the cache files every time I run the website in the browser.  Is there any way I can get it to not have this problem?  Running the website on Centos 6.4, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two solutions to this problem, both involve using `chmod` and `chown`.

**Solution 1:**

Move whatever your cronjob runs into its own shell script, and tell cron to run your shell script instead.

After your original command runs, run `chmod` and `chown` to change the permissions as you want.

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Do your stuff here\n"
DIR_ROOT="./your-dir-here/"
find $DIR_ROOT -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664 # make all files user+group r+w
find $DIR_ROOT -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 775 # make all directories user+group r+w+x
chown apache:apache -r $DIR_ROOT
```

**Solution 2:**

Instead of using a shell script, you could append a semicolon to the command your cronjob runs, and then add `chmod` and `chown`.

```
*/5 * * * * /my/five/minute/script.sh; chmod 664 ./some-file; chown apache:apache ./some-file
```

Hope that helps.

*Note: Both solutions are intentionally not the same, I want you to try to think your way through this.*